# VC++ CefSharp Import Win32 -> x64 error

Tags: visual-c++, 64-bit, cefsharp

In VS2013 Community Edition, I had a Win32 VC++ clr project I've been working on. I'm trying to use the CefSharp library, and so through nuget I've imported it.

Following the steps found [here](http://thechriskent.com/2014/08/18/embedded-chromium-in-winforms/) I learned I had to change from Win32 to x64 as my 'Active solution platform' to avoid this:

```
error : CefSharp.Common does not work correctly on 'Win32' platform. You need to specify platform (x86 / x64).
```

However when I follow those steps and add x64 to my project through the configuration manager, I get the following compilation errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: PROJECTNAME, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>  Main.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\system_error(20): error C2869: 'std::errc' : has already been defined to be a namespace
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\system_error(101): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'generic_errno'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\system_error(101): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\system_error(101): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
```

I'm not sure what is causing this or how to solve it.

Comment: I've created an issue to at some point add `Win32` as platform https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1338

Comment: It might be worth trying the latest `CI` build which is compiled using `VC++ 2013`, the latest release version (`43.0.0`) is compiled using `VC++ 2012`. A quick google suggests this may be a problem using two different versions of `VC++`, I haven't tested this theory.

Feed details for the `CI` builds can be found here https://www.myget.org/gallery/cefsharp

Comment: So the error is caused by the CefSharp library? FYI I still get the error with no imports in my code, and a bear .cpp file

Comment: It was just a theory. What happens if you create a new project and switch to x64?